# Why backslash is present before variable in eval statement?

Tags: php, eval

While learning PHP online I am stopped at this `eval` function please help me. Why is there is a slash before `$str2` in `eval` statement?

```
<?php
$string = "beautiful";
$time = "winter";

$str = 'This is a $string $time morning!';
echo $str. "<br>";

eval("\$str2 = \"$str\";");
echo $str2;
?>
```

Comment: The backslash is to escape the '$' sign. The statement $str="str"; will be evaluated.

Comment: \$str2 mask the $ so you build the variable **$str2** in eval() btw stop useing eval() function until you don't need it .. eval is evil :)

Comment: Yup eval is evil u should avoid using it as far as possible

Answer (score 1):

The slash escapes the dollar sign, else in double quotes the dollar signs starts a variable name.

```
echo $var; // print the content of $var
echo "$var"; // print the content of $var
echo "\$var"; // print '$var'
echo '$var'; // print '$var'
```

Other thing is that you should find another book/tutorial for studying. Usign eval is unrecommended and in this case bad.

The last two lines of your code should be:

```
$str2 = $str;
echo $str2;
```

OR just

```
echo $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

eval parses a string as php code, if you would remove them, both `$str` and `$str2` would be replaced by their contents before it would get parsed by `eval`.

So with backslashes it would parse

```
$str2 = "This is a beautiful winter morning!";
```

Without the backslash it would parse

```
undefined = "This is a beautiful winter morning!";
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it help identify that variable is used and variable with backslash are recognized by Compiler and then  variable name is replaced with the value that it represents.

Answer (score 0):

Backslash used to recognize PHP specials characters. In this case, \$str2 indicating a string contain "$str" not a variable named $str which is value  'This is a $string $time morning!'. So \$ while printed as string $ not as a variable.